# How would I setup IIS7 as a SSL reverse proxy?

Tags: iis-7

I'm running Widows 2008 EE with IIS 7.  I'd like to setup a reverse proxy with the SSL terminating on my Windows box, then proxying HTTP connections to a mix of IIS and Apache machines internally.  So, to clarify (where -> means "proxied to"):

```
https://www.mydomain.com/svn -> http://myinternalsvnsrv/svn

https://www.mydomain.com/redmine -> http://myinternalredminesrv
```

etc...

Ideally, I wouldn't use any third-party add-ins like [UrlRewriter](http://www.managedfusion.com/products/url-rewriter/).  Is this possible with only IIS7?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes; see [Reverse Proxy with URL Rewrite v2 and Application Request Routing](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/659/reverse-proxy-with-url-rewrite-v2-and-application-request-routing/).

Answer (score 2):

I can confirm that crb's comment is correct.

I now have redmine and svn both served up using his suggestion. Works a charm. My arrangement is using subdomains, e.g. ://redmine.domain.com and ://svn.domain.com, but either will definitely work.

> My earlier comment:
>
> Sorry for the bad form, but I see no
> way to PM GuyBehindTheGuy, including
> on his blog, and I've gotta know: Did
> this work? I have exactly the same
> requirements, in fact, the same apps
> (SVN and RedMine), and would love to
> achieve this same configuration. I've
> been working on a lot of
> configurations before now, non
> satisfactory, and this seems ideal.
> Can you confirm this worked?

Comment: In short, no.  I could not get the URL Rewrite module working correctly.  I have no doubt it was simply my ignorance of IIS 7.  I even tried Managed Fusion's URL Rewriter http://urlrewriter.codeplex.com/ with no success.  But again, it was more a question of wrestling with IIS 7 than a problem with the idea.  

In the end, we got it working with Apache, but it wasn't easy.

BTW--I added a way to e-mail me on my blog.  I must have accidentally deleted it a few months back.  Thanks for the heads up!  :-)

Comment: Thanks GuyBehindTheGuy. For clarity, I did succeed with this approach, as I have updated my post to convey. It's quite elegant.

Comment: @RogerRogers - Would it be possible for you to post the relevant portions of the web.config?  (I believe all of the IIS7 settings are in there.)  I'd be interested to see what it took to get it working.  Thanks!